# Ajax call to API which returns JSON

Tags: json, ajax, api

I have created a restful API which currently returns the following JSON as a list when accessed via the URL `localhost:52359/API/Brands`.

```
[{"brand_id":1,"brand_name":"brand1"},{"brand_id":2,"brand_name":"brand2"}]
```

I also have a Ajax call to my API which is as follows:

```
$ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "localhost:52359/API/Brands",
datatype:"JSON",
success: {
}
```

What needs to be included in the success so that my data from API is retuned in JSON and is logged to the console as I only want to currently test that data is being retrieved from the api using this Ajax call.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow please read formatting help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting this helps a lot while reading questions.

Comment: There is shorthand for this kind of request check https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I visited the link you provided and followed it's guidance. U fortunately I am returning [object object] from my API.

Comment: Read the docs carefully - $.getJSON works different it does  NOT return string but an object.